# change of variable isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let K be a field and let $\alpha\in K$. I'm asked to show the existence of a unique homomorphism $\tau_{\alpha}:K[x] \rightarrow K[x] $ given by $\tau_{\alpha}(x)=x-\alpha$ and show that $\tau_{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism. I believe this is called a change of variable isomorphism. However it seems to me the transformation is not even linear, can someone help me with what I am missing here?

Comment: When you say linear, do you mean linear over $K$ or over $K[x]$? 

It might help to try to look at some examples of what $\tau_\alpha$ does. For example, what is $\tau_\alpha(1)$? $\tau_\alpha(2)$? How about $\tau_\alpha(2x)$? $\tau_\alpha(x^2)$? Given a polynomial $f(x)$ can you write out explicitly what $\tau_\alpha(f(x))$ has to be?

Comment: Perhaps this is your confusion: when it says $\tau_\alpha(x)=x-\alpha$, it does not mean that $\tau_\alpha(f)=f-\alpha$ for all $f\in K[x]$.  Here $x$ is not a variable standing for an arbitrary element of $K[x]$; rather it is the specific polynomial "$x$", which is one particular element of $K[x]$.

Comment: But then isn't it weird that the function is defined as $K[x] \rightarrow K[x]$? I feel like I should assume it means $\tau_{\alpha}(f(x))=f(x-\alpha)$, but it is awkward the way the question is worded.

Comment: To Ben FL: when I said its not linear I mean that if $\tau_{\alpha}(x)=x-\alpha$ then $\tau_{\alpha}(x+y)\neq \tau_{\alpha}(x)+\tau_{\alpha}(y)$

Answer (score 1):

It is tough to tell what you mean by "linear". You have to define the map on all of $K[x]$. To do this, for $a_k \in K$ define $\tau_a(\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx^k) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x-\alpha)^k $. Check to see that $\tau_{\alpha}$ is an isomorphism. To show uniqueness, suppose that $\phi$ is another homomorphism with this property. Then,

\begin{align*}
\phi(\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx^k) & = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k(\phi(x))^k \text{  since $\phi$ is a homomorphism} \\ 
& = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x - \alpha)^k \text{  since $\phi(x) = x - \alpha $} \\
& = \tau_a(\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx^k)
\end{align*}

Thus, $\phi = \tau_{\alpha}$ establishing uniqueness.